# Iterating through variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a variable called 'files' that contains `/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv` directories and names.

Now i need to iterate through the items in `files` variable and print it

I've tried :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $files; do
    echo item: $i
done
```

Comment: (1) Storing a list of names in a single string is bad practice in the first place. Don't do that -- use an array; this is necessary because filenames, like regular string variables, can contain any character except the NUL, so there's no reliable way to know when one name ends and the next one starts. (2) Regular shell variables aren't accessible to subprocesses -- only environment variables are. If you need a segment of script to access non-exported variables, source it into your shell, don't execute it as a subprocess.

Comment: (You can export a regular string variable, but you *can't* export an array, so fixing the inappropriate use of an string to store a list is incompatible with using `export` to expose the data to subprocesses).

Comment: ...anyhow, to be a complete question, you need to show not just your code but also your actual behavior and invocation method. I've made some informed guesses about the above in prior comments, but it's not a complete question unless those details are actually [edit]ed into the text.

Comment: (Showing *how* you set the variable, in the context of how you run the script is also essential; I'm *guessing* it's a non-exported shell variable only present in a parent shell, but that's just a guess until you show it in the question).

Comment: ...you might try running `declare -p files >&2` in the parent process from which you start the script, and then putting `declare -p files >&2` inside the script itself; the difference itself is liable to be informative (if the above guesses are correct, the variable *simply isn't set* inside the script's runtime environment, and you'll get an error message reflecting that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 2 worked . Also i want to i have to test if file exists `if test -e ~$file; then echo "File exists"; else echo "File doesn't exist $file"; fi` but is it right with tilde or how do i concatenate them

Comment: Do you mean `~/$file`? `~$file` doesn't make any sense; `~username` is an expansion that takes place *before* parameter expansions happen, so you can't use it to fill out a PE.

Comment: Seriously, though, `for i in $files` is innately, unfixably buggy. Run `mkdir -p ~/'directory with * and spaces'` and then try to put a file in that directory in the list.

Comment: For that matter, `echo item: $i` (or even just `echo $i`) is buggy too; see [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: The thing to do instead -- the thing that *isn't* buggy -- is `files=( /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv )` (creating an array), then `./your-script "${files[@]}"` (calling the script with the array expanded onto its command line), then `for i in "$@"; do printf 'item: %s\n' "$i"; done` (iterating over command-line arguments; you could also `printf 'item: %s\n' "$@"` to let `printf` do the iteration for you).

Comment: So i've done this `for file in $files; do
 echo $file
 if test -e ~/data/$file; then echo $file >> oldFiles.txt; else echo "File doesn't exist $file"; fi
done` I needed to write existing files to txt file

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net, and follow the links in its results.